# C# find a specific line from a text file / display to listview

Tags: c#, listview, substring

Here are the steps:
1. Browse to a text file
2. Load the text to a text box
3. find specific lines/location from the text
4. display in a 3 column LISTVIEW.

The way i'm doing it right now is this:

```
listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "1", "Type", text1.Substring(0, 12) }));

listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "2", "ID", text1.Substring(13, 2) }));

listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "3", "Name", text1.Substring(15, 3) }));

listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "4", "DOB", text1.Substring(17, 2) }));

listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "5", "Version", text1.Substring(18, 7) }));
```

It's working.... until i come across a textfile that has a length less than my substring codes. I get a crash (OutOfRangeException)

I was wondering if there's any better way of coding this.  If not, what's the best approach on getting around the OutOfRangeExceptiion error.

As a work around, i'm doing text1.padright(999) to increase the length of any text file i load.  But there probably is a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest to add extension method like this:

```
public static class Ext 
{
    public static string SubstringWithCheck(this string text, int start, int length, string replace = "")
    {
        if (text.Length < start + length)
        {
            return replace;
        }
        return text.Substring(start, length);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this method:

```
listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "1", "Type", text1.SubstringWithCheck(0, 12) }));
```

Or like this:

```
listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "1", "Type", text1.SubstringWithCheck(0, 12, "your text here") }));
```